# How to implement this Java mechanism in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

In `Java`, the abstract class's static member will be inherited all through its subclasses.
like

```
abstract class TopThing{
  public TopThing next;
  public TopThing(TopThing tt){
        this.next = tt
  }

  private static HashTable<String, TopThing> someTable = new HashTable<String,TopThing>();
  protected void add(String name) {
      someTable.put(name, this);
  public static Parent forName(String name) {
      return someTable.get(name)    ;
  }
}

class SomeSpecific extends TopThing {
    public final String name;
    public SomeSpecific (String name, TopThing tt) {
       super(tt);
       this.name = name;
       this.add(name);
}
```

This is I am first time writing in Scala, 
the only way I know to achieve the above is using companion object, but it seems does not work for this case

- Can companion object store the private static table? (it seems no...)
- If I can declare the table in the companion object, can it be
  referenced from companion class? ( it seems no...)
- In the `add` method, how can the subclass's instance referred and be inserted into the table? (the question is also about `this` in `add` method)
- What's a good practice of this in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, it can.
2. Yes, you reference it as `TopThing.someTable` (or just `someTable` after `import TopThing._`).
3. Same as in Java: `this`. So

   ```
   abstract class TopThing(val next: TopThing) {
     protected def add(name: String) {
       TopThing.someTable += (name -> this)
     }
   }

   object TopThing {
     private val someTable = collection.mutable.Map[String,TopThing]()

     def forName(name: String) = someTable.get(name)
   }

   class SomeSpecific(val name: String, next: TopThing) extends TopThing(next) {
     this.add(name)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For question 1: you can use private[namespace]

For question 2: no,  but you can use import

```
class Xxx {
  import Xxx._
  ...
}
```

For question 3: I don't known how to answer it.

For question 4:

```
trait TopThing {
  val someTable: HashTable[String, TopThing] 
}
class Xxx extend TopThing {
  val someTable = Xxx.someTable  
}
```

Comment: "I don't known how to answer it."  I'd love to have this on a quality t-shirt.  Preferably with a lolcat.  Also, I would +1 for answering bullet #4, except that someTable should be theTable, I think, as in the other response.

Comment: Putting the table in a trait will create one _per instance_ which is not at all the same thing as the Java code's _static_ table.